# Oracle: Not able to create tablespace from stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, stored-procedures, permissions, tablespaces

I am trying to create tablespace from stored procedure.

```
create or replace procedure testprc 
is
query_string VARCHAR2(4000);
tbs_name VARCHAR2(20):='test77';
begin
dbms_output.put_line('test..');

query_string := 'CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE '|| tbs_name || ' DATAFILE '''|| tbs_name || '.dat'' SIZE 1G REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON ONLINE';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_string;

end;
/
```

But when I execute the stored procedure,

```
execute testprc
```

I am getting the following error:

test..

> BEGIN testprc; END;
>
> - ERROR at line 1: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TESTPRC", line 10 ORA-06512: at line 1

When I create the tablespace from sqlplus, it is created successfully. I have connected to sqlplus as system user.

Please help me in fixing this and your help will be valuable.

Comment: User has Create tablespace system privilege. Also i am able to create tablespace directly from sqlplus. System is the user i used to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block (stored procedure, function, or trigger) that executes with definer's rights. Roles are not used for privilege checking and you cannot set roles within a definer's rights procedure.
>   [More](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#GUID-5C57B842-AF82-4462-88E9-5E9E8FD59874)

First of all dont create object under `SYSTEM` schema. Second in order to execute commands in PL/SQL you should have privileges granted directly to the user not from role. And `SYSTEM` user inherits the `CREATE TABLESPACE` system privilege via `DBA` role, so that you are able to create tablespace directly not from PL/SQL procedure.

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba

SQL> grant create tablespace to system;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn system/password
Connected.

SQL> exec testprc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: i am not able to connect as sysdba. SQL> conn / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>

Comment: you are awesome... you rocked man.. may be i will trouble you lot by asking questions related to oracle. :P .. hope you will help me.. @JSapkota...